# mysql group by rows

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, where-clause

The Data:

```
"Name","Art","unterkunft_id","optionen_id"
"FeWo üöä","Ferienwohnung","5","2"
"FeWo üöä","Ferienwohnung","5","4"
"hotel","Hotel","3","3"
"hotel","Hotel","3","4"
```

The Query returning this:

```
SELECT  `booking_unterkuenfte`.Name,  `booking_unterkunftart`.Art, booking_unterkuenfte_optionen . * 
  FROM booking_unterkuenfte, booking_unterkunftart, booking_unterkuenfte_optionen
  WHERE  `booking_unterkuenfte`.unterkunftsart_id = booking_unterkunftart.id
  AND booking_unterkuenfte_optionen.unterkunft_id = booking_unterkuenfte.id
  GROUP BY booking_unterkuenfte.id
  ORDER BY pos DESC , Name ASC 
  LIMIT 0 , 30
```

If i select multiple options, i get null result. I know why but not how to fix :(

```
  SELECT  `booking_unterkuenfte`.Name,  `booking_unterkunftart`.Art, booking_unterkuenfte_optionen . * 
  FROM booking_unterkuenfte, booking_unterkunftart, booking_unterkuenfte_optionen
  WHERE  `booking_unterkuenfte`.unterkunftsart_id = booking_unterkunftart.id
  AND booking_unterkuenfte_optionen.unterkunft_id = booking_unterkuenfte.id
  AND booking_unterkuenfte_optionen.optionen_id =4
  AND booking_unterkuenfte_optionen.optionen_id =3
  GROUP BY booking_unterkuenfte.id
  ORDER BY pos DESC , Name ASC 
  LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Should return the Hotel, because it has both options. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you an option is either 3 or 4, never **both**, so those two ANDs evaluate to an empty query. You need to perform a multiple JOIN against booking_unterkuenfte_optionen, if you know how many options you are going to test against.

```
SELECT  `booking_unterkuenfte`.Name,  `booking_unterkunftart`.Art,
   booking_unterkuenfte_optionen.* 
FROM booking_unterkuenfte, booking_unterkunftart,
     booking_unterkuenfte_optionen AS op1,
     booking_unterkuenfte_optionen AS op2
WHERE  `booking_unterkuenfte`.unterkunftsart_id = booking_unterkunftart.id

AND op1.unterkunft_id = booking_unterkuenfte.id
AND op1.optionen_id =4

AND op2.unterkunft_id = booking_unterkuenfte.id
AND op2.optionen_id =3

GROUP BY booking_unterkuenfte.id
ORDER BY pos DESC , Name ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Another way, if you are sure that no option is reported twice for the same unterkunft_id, would be to count them. You require that optionen is in (3, 4) and that the number of optionen is 2; if (3,3) cannot be present, this means you found an entry with both 3 and 4.

```
SELECT  `booking_unterkuenfte`.Name,  `booking_unterkunftart`.Art,
   COUNT(booking_unterkuenfte_optionen.unterkunft_id) AS matches
FROM booking_unterkuenfte
JOIN booking_unterkunftart ON (booking_unterkuenfte.unterkunftsart_id = booking_unterkunftart.id)
JOIN booking_unterkuenfte_optionen ON (booking_unterkuenfte_optionen.unterkunft_id = booking_unterkuenfte.id)
WHERE
    booking_unterkuenfte_optionen.optionen_id IN (3,4)
GROUP BY booking_unterkuenfte.id
HAVING matches = 2
ORDER BY pos DESC , Name ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I advise in favor of adopting shorter names and aliases, for example

```
...booking_unterkunfte AS bu
JOIN booking_unterkunftart AS bua ON (...)
JOIN booking_unterkuenfte_optionen AS buo ON (buo.u_id = bu.id)
...
```

Comment: booking_unterkuenfte_optionen IN (3,4) 
must be

    booking_unterkuenfte_optionen.optionen_id IN (3,4)
but this is working. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, will edit. I got tangled in all those optionen :-) -- consider using aliases to get shorter names!